# What is probability in phone number with $7$ digit that no numbers occur more than one time?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Hi I learn for exam and I find task in internet but no answer. Task is I translate and sorry for bad English:

> Calculate probability that in a $7$ digit phone number, no digit occur
>   more than once. All digit of phone number have same probability. Hint:
>   You have that $32 \cdot 27 \cdot 7 = 6048$

I understanded task but not the hint... $7$ digit phone number you have how many possibles? You have $10^7$ possibles but then there is all possibles, also that more number are in phone number. We only want each number one time.

We make $7!$ that we have permutation of all $7$ number who occur in phone number, so all number one time. In total probability is $\frac{7!}{10^7}= 0.0504$%

Are task correct solved?

**Edit: Pls also check other question the person who answer no more tolk with me... : [Calculate probability for event $\sum_{i=1}^{100}Z_{i} \in \left(-10,10\right )$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2467577/calculate-probability-for-event-sum-i-1100z-i-in-left-10-10-right/2467590?noredirect=1#comment5098577_2467590)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the $7$ numbers distinct, for the first position, you have $10$ choices between $0$ to $9$. For the second position, you have $9$ choices in $0$ to $9$ except the number in the first position.

So the total number of $7$ digit phone number is $10 \cdot 9 \ldots \cdot 4 = 604800$.

The answer is $\frac{604800}{10^7}$.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that there are $10^7$ phone numbers, but there are more with different digits.  How many choices for the first digit?  How many are left for the second digit?  On to the seventh?  I have no clue about the hint involving $6048$

Comment: Task are confused me I think because we have 10 number in total we make $$\frac{10!}{10^7}$$ ?

Comment: There are ten digits to choose from, but only seven spots in a phone number. So what you have correctly about $10!$ is that it starts at $10$. What you have wrong is that it goes all the way down to $1$ when it shouldn't.

Comment: Ok I understand thank you all!!

Answer (score 2):

If we were to make a phone number with seven digits without any repetitions, there are ten options for the first digit, nine for the second, and so on. Your answer implies that this starts at $7$ instead of $10$, which is wrong.

Write the calculation out, simplify one or two factors of $10$, and you should see where the hint comes from as well.

Comment: I make comment in Ross Millikan answer is it good?

Answer (score 1):

I know you seem to already understand the answer, but this is to try to explain the reason for the question giving you the hint. It may have been for the following:

$$\frac{_{10}P_{7}}{10^7}$$
$$ $$

$$=\frac{\frac{10*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1}{3*2*1}}{10*10*10*10*10*10*10}$$
$$ $$

$$=\frac{(32*27*7)10*6*5*2*1}{6} * \frac{1}{10*10*10*10*10*10*10}$$

$$ $$ 
$$=\frac{6048 * 10}{10*10*10*10*10*10}$$

$$ $$
$$=\frac{6048}{10^5}$$

$$ $$

$$=0.06048$$

No calculator needed :) although it would be much faster to actually use one. But I feel that this is one of the best ways to take advantage of the hint.